# Decode two JSON strings that have been concatenated via ws_concat(mysql) using SQL, PHP or JS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

A bit of 'might be asking the impossible' question here so I will simplify best I can.

I have the following table/columns in a mysql DB:

```
*users*
first_name
last_name
```

In my application to retrieve these columns, I a run SQL statement like so:

```
SELECT ws_concat(user.first_name, user.last_name) as author
FROM users;
```

(I have to run the query using raw SQL for pushing to ES purposes)

I then have a access to the results in PHP which is as expected.

If first_name and last_name are stored as JSON values then the resulting author field will look like:

{
  author: ""Ryan" "H""
}

I need to display this name correctly in multiple views.

How can I JSON decode two concatenated JSON strings?

Ideally I would like to achieve at the SQL level but I think its not possible to be done in the query? so how would I be able to achieve this using PHP or JS?

Thanks

Example:

```
first_name: "RY&#193;&#209;"
last_name: "H&#193;d"
```

Stored in users table.

Retrieved via this query

```
SELECT ws_concat(user.first_name, user.last_name) as author
FROM users;
```

Would return the following:

```
{ author: ""RY&#193;&#209;" ""H&#193;d"" }
```

Author needs to be displayed in a view like:

**RYÁÑ HÁd**

Comment: Why are the `_name` fields storing the value *including the quotes*?! Or aren't they?

Comment: They are stored as a "JSON" string so if a _name field was to contain a UTF-8 character it would be stored as something like "Ry&#196;n".

Comment: Please share some example data for the user table. Use formatted text

Comment: I would probably start there with a fix… that sounds somewhat insane to be honest. You also don't seem to be processing those concatenated strings using proper JSON functions then, but you're purely working with concatenation to build the final JSON? Also not very sane…

Comment: I have to do this way to support UTF-8 characters in the db without changing the encoding within the DB system (this is not an option). I have to rely on the raw SQL statement in PHP to retrieve all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple logic.

Retrieve the names like so :-

```
SELECT users.first_name as first_name, users.last_name as last_name
FROM users;
```

Then JSON decode each part of the name separately and concat the decoded values together and assign an author property after the query has been completed then send the data to view and display as expected.